# PostgreSQL join to denormalize a table with generate_series

Tags: postgresql, join, denormalization, generate-series

I've this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "mytable"
(  name text,  count integer );
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('john', 4),('mark',2),('albert',3);
```

and I would like "denormlize" the rows in this way:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable JOIN generate_series(1,4) tmp(a) ON (a<=count)
```

so I've a number of rows for each name equals to the count column: I've 4 rows with john, 2 with mark and 3 with albert.
But i can't use the generate_series() function if I don't know the highest count (in this case 4). There is a way to do this without knowing the MAX(count) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name, 
       generate_series(1,count)
from mytable;
```

Set returning functions can be used in the `select` list and will do a cross join with the row retrieved from the base table.

I *think* this is an undocumented behaviour that might go away in the future, but I'm not sure about that (I recall some discussion regarding this on the mailing list)

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/05773/1)

Comment: extremely elegant solution! I like it!

Comment: I was surprised by that behavior when I first saw it in another question/answer some days ago. I think it is worth its own question.

Comment: There are indeed [two examples of generate_subscripts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) in the select list, one of them doing a cross join. So I guess it is here to stay.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE ztable ;
CREATE TABLE ztable (zname varchar, zvalue INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO ztable(zname, zvalue) VALUES( 'one', 1), ( 'two', 2 ), ( 'three', 3) , ( 'four', 4 );

WITH expand AS (
        WITH RECURSIVE zzz AS (
        SELECT 1::integer AS rnk , t0.zname
        FROM ztable t0
        UNION
        SELECT 1+rr.rnk , t1.zname
        FROM ztable t1
        JOIN zzz rr ON rr.rnk < t1.zvalue
        )
        SELECT zzz.zname
        FROM zzz
        )
SELECT x.*
FROM expand x
        ;
```